# Ruby: Find index of next match in array, or find with offset

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to find further matches after `Array#find_index { |item| block }` matches for the first time. How can I search for the index of the second match, third match, and so on?

In other words, I want the equivalent of the `pos` argument to `Regexp#match(str, pos)` for `Array#find_index`. Then I can maintain a current-position index to continue the search.

I cannot use `Enumerable#find_all` because I might modify the array between calls (in which case, I will also adjust my current-position index to reflect the modifications). I do not want to copy part of the array, as that would increase the [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) of my algorithm. I want to do this without copying the array:

```
new_pos = pos + array[pos..-1].find_index do |elem|
    elem.matches_condition?
end
```

The following are different questions. They only ask the first match in the array, plus one:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300886/ruby-how-to-find-the-next-match-in-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300886)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596517/ruby-find-next-in-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596517)

The following question is closer, but still does not help me, because I need to process the first match before continuing to the next (and this way also conflicts with modification):

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925654/ruby-find-in-array-with-offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925654)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do it is just:

```
new_pos = pos
while new_pos < array.size and not array[new_pos].matches_condition?
    new_pos += 1
end
new_pos = nil if new_pos == array.size
```

In fact, I think this is probably better than my other answer, because it's harder to get wrong, and there's no chance of future shadowing problems being introduced from the surrounding code. However, it's still clumsy.

And if the condition is more complex, then you end up needing to do something like this:

```
new_pos = pos
# this check is only necessary if pos may be == array.size
if new_pos < array.size
    prepare_for_condition
end
while new_pos < array.size and not array[new_pos].matches_condition?
    new_pos += 1
    if new_pos < array.size
        prepare_for_condition
    end
end
new_pos = nil if new_pos == array.size
```

Or, God forbid, a `begin ... end while` loop (although then you run into trouble with the initial value of `new_pos`):

```
new_pos = pos - 1
begin
    new_pos += 1
    if new_pos < array.size
        prepare_for_condition
    end
end while new_pos < array.size and not array[new_pos].matches_condition?
new_pos = nil if new_pos == array.size
```

This may seem horrible. However, supposing `prepare_for_condition` is something that keeps being tweaked in small ways. Those tweaks will eventually get refactored; however, by that time, the output of the refactored code will also end up getting tweaked in small ways that don't belong with the old refactored code, but do not yet seem to justify refactoring of their own - and so on. Occasionally, someone will forget to change both places. This may seem pathological; however, in programming, as we all know, the pathological case has a habit of occurring only too often.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way this can be done.  We can define a new method in `Array` class that will allow us to find indexes that match a given condition.  The condition can be specified as block that returns boolean.

The new method returns an `Enumerator` so that we get the benefit of many of the `Enumerator` methods such `next`, `to_a`, etc.

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

class Array
  def find_index_r(&block)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder| 
      self.each_with_index{|i, j| yielder.yield j if block.call(i)}
    end
  end
end

e = ary.find_index_r { |r| r % 2 == 0 }

p e.to_a  #=> [1, 3, 5]
p e.next  
#=> 1
p e.next  
#=> 3
ary[2]=10 
p ary
#=> [1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6]
p e.next  
#=> 5
e.rewind
p e.next  
#=> 1
p e.next  
#=> 2
```

<sub>**Note:** I added a new method in `Array` class for demonstration purpose.  Solution can be adapted easily to work without the monkey-patching</sub>

Comment: I like your approach but you're doing way too much. Everything inside your `Enumerator.new` block can be replaced with `each_with_index {|item, idx| yielder.yield(idx) if block.call(item) }`. Take a look: http://ideone.com/7jOyqQ

Comment: Thanks @Jordan - I have updated my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: But is this still guaranteed to work if I modify the array between calls to e.next?

Comment: @martinjs  Not sure what kind of modification you are talking about.  If you update an element that has already been traversed, you will not see the effect until you execute `Enumerator#rewind`

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one way to do it would be:

```
new_pos = pos + (pos...array.size).find_index do |index|
    elem = array[index]
    elem.matches_condition?
end
```

However, this is clumsy and easy to get wrong. For example, you may forget to add `pos`. Also, you have to make sure `elem` isn't shadowing something. Both of these can lead to hard-to-trace bugs.

I find it hard to believe that an index argument to `Array#find_index` and `Array#index` still hasn't made it into the language. However, I notice `Regexp#match(str,pos)` wasn't there until version 1.9, which is equally surprising.

Comment: Why do you post an answer that is *"clumsy and easy to get wrong"*?

Comment: Because in certain cases this will be your only (or best) option, barring monkey-patching. I would like to convince the Ruby team that they should add a position (or offset) argument to the standard library method #find_index (and probably others too).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
arr = [9,1,4,1,9,36,25]
findees = [1,6,3,6,3,7]
proc = ->(n) { n**2 }
```

and for each element `n` in `findees` we want the index of the first unmatched element `m` of `arr` for `which proc[n] == m`. For example, if `n=3`, then `proc[3] #==> 9`, so the first matching index in `arr` would be `0`. For the next `n=3` in `findees`, the first unmatched match in `arr` is at index `4`.

We can do this like so:

```
arr = [9,1,4,1,9,36,25]
findees = [1,6,3,6,3,7]
proc = ->(n) { n**2 }

h = arr.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(n,i),h| h[n] << i }
  #=> {9=>[0, 4], 1=>[1, 3], 4=>[2], 36=>[5], 25=>[6]}
findees.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| v=h[proc[n]]; a << v.shift if v }
  #=> [1, 5, 0, nil, 4, nil]
```

We can generalize this into a handy `Array` method as follow:

```
class Array
  def find_indices(*args)
    h = each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |(n,i),h| h[n] << i }
    args.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| v=h[yield n]; a << v.shift if v }
  end
end

arr.find_indices(*findees) { |n| n**2 }
  #=> [1, 5, 0, nil, 4, nil]

arr = [3,1,2,1,3,6,5]
findees = [1,6,3,6,3,7]
arr.find_indices(*findees, &:itself)
  #=> [1, 5, 0, nil, 4, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is not much different from the others but perhaps packaged cleaner to be syntactically similar to Array#find_index .  Here's the compact form.

```
def find_next_index(a,prior=nil)
    (((prior||-1)+1)...a.length).find{|i| yield a[i]}
end
```

Here's a simple test case.

```
test_arr = %w(aa ab ac ad)
puts find_next_index(test_arr){|v| v.include?('a')}
puts find_next_index(test_arr,1){|v| v.include?('a')}
puts find_next_index(test_arr,3){|v| v.include?('a')}

# evaluates to:
#     0
#     2
#     nil
```

And of course, with a slight rewrite you could monkey-patch it into the Array class